# how to change Blazor WASM identity net core 3.1 messages "You are logged out", "checking login state" and "authorizing"?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, identityserver4, blazor, webassembly

I need to know how to personalize and/or change language for this messages, I suppose it has to do with IdentityServer4.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What you are looking for is the `RemoteAuthenticatorView` .

You can find more details for your answer in the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/webassembly/additional-scenarios?view=aspnetcore-3.1#customize-the-authentication-user-interface).

```
@page "/security/{action}"
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication

<RemoteAuthenticatorView Action="@Action">
    @*authentication/login*
    <LoggingIn></LoggingIn> 
    @*authentication/login-callback*
    <CompletingLoggingIn></CompletingLoggingIn>
    @*authentication/login-failed*
    <LogInFailed></LogInFailed>
    @*authentication/logout*
    <LogOut></LogOut>
    @*authentication/logout-callback*
    <CompletingLogOut></CompletingLogOut>
    @*authentication/logout-failed*
    <LogOutFailed></LogOutFailed>
    @*authentication/logged-out*
    <LogOutSucceeded></LogOutSucceeded>
    @*authentication/profile*
    <UserProfile></UserProfile>
    @*authentication/register*
    <Registering></Registering>
</RemoteAuthenticatorView>

@code{
    [Parameter]
    public string Action { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

It is necessary to add some tags in **Authentication.razor** component:

```
@page "/authentication/{action}"
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication

<RemoteAuthenticatorView Action="@Action">
    <LogInFailed>
        <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">@strLogInFailed</div>
    </LogInFailed>
    <LogOut>
        <div class="alert alert-info" role="alert">@strLogOut</div>
    </LogOut>
    <LogOutSucceeded>
        <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">@strLogOutSucceeded</div>
    </LogOutSucceeded>
    <LoggingIn>
        <div class="alert alert-info" role="alert">@strLoggingIn</div>
    </LoggingIn>
    <CompletingLoggingIn>
        <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">@strCompletingLoggingIn</div>
    </CompletingLoggingIn>
</RemoteAuthenticatorView>

@code {
    [Parameter] public string Action { get; set; }

    string strLogInFailed = "Your login was not successful.";
    string strLogOut = "Trying to close your session.";
    string strLogOutSucceeded = "Your session has been closed successfully.";
    string strLoggingIn = "Redirecting to the login screen.";
    string strCompletingLoggingIn = "Your login was successful.";
}
```

I found how to do it in: [Custom Authentication User Interface](https://code-maze.com/how-to-secure-blazor-webassembly-with-identityserver4/#custom-auth-ui) which, by the way, explains a lot on

> How to Secure Blazor WebAssembly with IdentityServer4

After read it, I also check the [RemoteAuthenticatorView Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.components.webassembly.authentication.remoteauthenticatorview?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

> Even accomplished this, still persist the "**Authorizing...**" message.

Answer (score 6):

To change the message "Authorizing..."

Need to add

```
<Authorizing>
     <h1>Authorization in progress</h1>
     <p>Only visible while authorization is in progress.</p>
</Authorizing>
```

to file App.razor

```
<CascadingAuthenticationState>
<Router AppAssembly="@typeof(Program).Assembly">
    <Found Context="routeData">
        <AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="@routeData" 
            DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
            <NotAuthorized>
                <h1>Sorry</h1>
                <p>You're not authorized to reach this page.</p>
                <p>You may need to log in as a different user.</p>
            </NotAuthorized>
            <Authorizing>
                <h1>Authorization in progress</h1>
                <p>Only visible while authorization is in progress.</p>
            </Authorizing>
        </AuthorizeRouteView>
    </Found>
    <NotFound>
        <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
            <h1>Sorry</h1>
            <p>Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</p>
        </LayoutView>
    </NotFound>
</Router>
```

You can find more details [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/?view=aspnetcore-5.0#customize-unauthorized-content-with-the-router-component).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `<Authorizing>` tag to override the default text.

```
   <AuthorizeView>
        <Authorizing>
            <p class="authorizing">Authorizing...</p>
        </Authorizing>
        <Authorized>
            <p class="authorized">Welcome, @context.User.Identity.Name!</p>
        </Authorized>
        <NotAuthorized>
            <p class="not-authorized">You're not authorized, @(context.User.Identity.Name ?? "anonymous")</p>
        </NotAuthorized>
    </AuthorizeView>
```

Source:

https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/1ed72f8f5f14dfc5a4ebc9d5d116d63792caa7fc/src/Components/test/testassets/BasicTestApp/AuthTest/AuthorizeViewCases.razor